# WooCommerce display price before add to cart

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to make the WooCommerce product price display before the "add to cart" button, however, I cant seem to get the price to display.

Here is the code I'm using in my **functions.php**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'misha_before_add_to_cart_btn' );
 
function misha_before_add_to_cart_btn(){
    echo '<div class="btn-price">'. $product->get_price_html().'</div>';
}
```

Please would someone be able to point out where I'm going wrong with the code that I'm using above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable $product is undefined when your function runs, you need to access the object to call the method get_price_html(). One way to do it is to call the global variable:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'misha_before_add_to_cart_btn' );
function misha_before_add_to_cart_btn(){
  global $product;
  echo '<div class="btn-price">'.$product->get_price_html().'</div>';
}
```